# Can Selenide be used alongside SpecFlow?

Tags: java, automated-tests, cucumber, specflow, selenide

I would like to know if it is possible to use SpecFlow along with the Selenide framework?

From my understanding, the fact that the Given/When/Then steps are all lumped together in each testing method with Selenide means that there is no ability to separate out the steps to be called via scenarios in the feature file without having to ditch using Selenide and move to just Specflow and Selenium instead.

Is this correct thinking or is there a way I can use both SpecFlow and Selenide for test automation?

My overall aim is to have a feature file(s) alongside my Selenide tests, to be able to run these feature files through another tool (e.g. using docs.picklesdoc.com) to be able to monitor the test automation process, hence my wondering if I can do this via SpecFlow.

Comment: SpecFlow is an extension for Visual Studio. Are you building a Java project in Visual Studio? So far as I can tell, Selenide is a Java library. SpecFlow is basically Cucumber for Visual Studio, with code written in C# or Visual Basic.

Comment: And what do you mean by "monitor the test automation process"?